# Interpolation in block: a problem

Tags: interpolation, syntax

Consider the following data:

```
data = Table[{x, 1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4}, {x, 0., 1, 0.01}];
```

I would like to interpolate the 1-d function f[x] made of `data[[All,{1,index}]]`, where `index = 2,3,4,5,6`. I find it convenient to use Block:

```
int[index_] := Block[{},
  inttemp[x_] = 
   Interpolation[data[[All, {1, index}]], InterpolationOrder -> 1][x];
  If[x < 1, inttemp[x], x^(index - 2)]
  ]
```

Unfortunately, something goes wrong:

```
function1[x_] = int[2];
function2[x_] = int[3];
function2[x_] = int[4];
```

Namely, the value of any previous launch of `int` duplicates the last function:

```
function1[0.2]
function2[0.2]
function3[0.2]
0.2^2
```

> 0.04

> 0.04

> 0.04

> 0.04

Most likely, the problem is in `If` condition, which postpones the definition of the function and causes interference between different callings of `int`.

Could you please tell me how to modify the `int` function in order to perform the interpolation properly?

Comment: Replace `Block[{},...]` by `Module[{inttemp},...]`. Alternatively, leave the Block and replace `inttemp[x_]` by `inttemp[index,x_]`, and also adjust where you call `inttemp`.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need any Block or Module, you can simply write:

```
function1[x_] = Interpolation[data[[All, {1, 2}]]][x];
function2[x_] = Interpolation[data[[All, {1, 3}]]][x];
function3[x_] = Interpolation[data[[All, {1, 4}]]][x];
function4[x_] = Interpolation[data[[All, {1, 5}]]][x];
```

To test you can plot the functions:

```
Plot[{function1[x], function2[x], function3[x], function4[x]}, {x, 0, 
  1}]
```

[image]